# most common words in array fileld postgres

Tags: python, django, postgresql, counter, aggregate-functions

I have a model with an array field in it. This field contains some words for each entity. Model is as follows :

```
class Entity(models.Model):
    words = ArrayField(
        models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True),
        null=True,
        blank=True
    )
```

I want to accumulate lists of all objects of this model and find 100 most common words occurred in these arrays. Is there any way to do this in Postgresql, or what is the efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

If approximate answers are good enough, and the table statistics are fairly accurate, you can use the array element statistics collected by PostgreSQL to solve your problem.

Assuming the table is called `public.entity` and the attribute is `words`, this query would produce the desired result:

```
SELECT mce.elem
FROM pg_stats s
   CROSS JOIN LATERAL
      unnest(most_common_elems::text::text[],
             most_common_elem_freqs) mce(elem, freq)
WHERE s.schemaname = 'public'
  AND s.tablename = 'entity'
  AND s.attname = 'words'
  AND mce.elem IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY mce.freq DESC
LIMIT 100;
```

Comment: Instead of executing raw query, is there any solution in Django?

Comment: I don't know Django, but I suspect that there can be nothing that won't read the whole table and count everything.